# Regarding property of Farey sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, farey-sequences

I am studying apostol Dirichlet series and modular functions book and struck upon this question. 
Question is - Two reduced fractions $a/ b$ and $c/d$ are called similarly ordered if $(c-a)(d-b) \ge 0$.
Prove that two neighbors $a_i / b_i$ and $a_{i+1}/ b_{i+1}$ in Farey fractions are similarly ordered. 
I tried using property $bc-ad=1$ for consecutive fractions but could prove  completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c<a$ and $d>b>0$, then $$\frac cd<\frac ad<\frac ab,$$ contraditcion.

If $c>a$ and $0<d<b$, then 
$$1=bc-ad>bc-cd=c(b-d)\ge 1\cdot 1, $$
contradiction.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Thank you

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen  can you please give some hint for 2nd part of the question  -  prove also that any two second neighbors $ a_i/ b_i and $ a_ i + 2 / b_i+2 are similarly ordered.   I tried using your approach used in proving 1 st part  but it doesn't work.